# How to see quickly packages have not been completed in the MASTER package?

Tags: ssis, ssms

First, here the context :

- In Visual Studio, we have a project that contains about 120 SSIS packages.
- These are launched in a MASTER package (with a "Execute Package Task" for each package that we want to run, because not all are active, only 70 packages. Each task is not related, they can run all together, we let SQL Server decides how to do it).
- The MASTER runs each night.
- When an error happens, we can see the error detail in SSMS (mainly network error).
- Then, we have a document that list all active packages that must run every night, and we launch manually those who doesn't ran.

My question:

How to write a SQL query to see quickly the packages that have not been completed in the MASTER package when an error occurred?

EDIT:

Here is the script of the Job:

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [SSIS_EXTRANET_DATAMART]    Script Date: 04/04/2023 09:17:34 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 04/04/2023 09:17:34 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'SSIS_EXTRANET_DATAMART', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'Pas de description disponible.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'XXX\xxxxx', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'EmailBI', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [DATAMART_V2]    Script Date: 04/04/2023 09:17:34 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'DATAMART_V2', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\EXTRANET\SSIS_EXTRANET\DATAMART_V2.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\"XXXXXXSSIS\SSIS\"" /ENVREFERENCE 29 /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0, 
        @proxy_name=N'xxxxxxxx'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Send Sucess Extranet]    Script Date: 04/04/2023 09:17:34 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Send Sucess Extranet', 
        @step_id=2, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = ''P_BI'',  
@recipients = ''bi@xxxxx.fr'' ,
@body = ''Refresh Ok '',  
@subject = ''Refresh Ok''', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

And here a screenshot of the MASTER package:

[image: MASTER package]

Comment: Do you run the packages in the Integration Services/SSISDB or are does this use the Package Deployment Model (deployed to file system/msdb/SSIS Package Store)?

Comment: We run the MASTER package into a Job in SQL Server Agent in SSMS

Comment: Could you post the job step definition for the SQL Agent in question?

Comment: I edited my message to include the script of the job and a screenshot of the MASTER package